# Having trouble with play again

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

So this is my code....I want to find a way how to play again... using while loop or other method.... can anyone help me with this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("enter minimum of Yahtzee dice 2-9: ");
    int min = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("enter maximum of Yahtzee dice 3-10: ");
    int max = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Dice   Rolls\tYahtzee's Percentage  Odds\t");
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= 5000000; j++) {
            Random generator = new Random();
            YahtzeeDice d = new YahtzeeDice(generator, i);
            if (d.IsAYahtzee()) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%d     ", i);
        System.out.printf("%d\t", 5000000);
        System.out.printf("%d\t  ", count);
        System.out.printf("%f   ", (double) count / 5000000);
        double per = count / (double) 5000000;
        int odds = (int) (1 / per);
        System.out.printf("1 in %d\n", odds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrap the code you want/need to execute several times into a `do-while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a surrounding loop code to your code, where you ask "Play again". Like this:

```
do{

   //your code

   System.out.print("Gib was ein: ");
   String answer = br.readLine();
}while(answer.equal("yes"))
```

you can put your code in a function, too.

```
do{

   mcFunction

   System.out.print("Gib was ein: ");
   String answer = br.readLine();
}while(answer.equal("yes"))

public void myFunction(){
   //your code
}
```